# What's the difference between vertex descriptor and index in Boost Graph Library?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

In Boost graph library, when should one use *vertex descriptor* and when *index*? Since the implementation of `vertex_descriptor` is actually unsigned integer, do the two things have the same value?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `vertex_descriptor` is only an index when you are using a vector (or similar) as the underlying data structure for your vertices (i.e. `boost::vecS`). If you use a different underlying data structure, then the vertex descriptors will not necessarily be an index. An example of this would be if you use an `std::list`/`boost::listS` - lists do not use an index-based accessing method. Instead, each `vertex_descriptor` will instead be a pointer to the list item.

Thus, every time you want to refer to a vertex in your graph, you should use `vertex_descriptor`. That way if you later decide to use a different data structure, you won't have to change your code.

For more information about the different `EdgeList` and `VertexList` data types and the pros/cons of each, see the [Using Adjacency List](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html) page.